# Simple types JSON serialization in ASP.net Web-api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I've created a web api, which contains method:

```
POST Settings/SetPropertyValue?propertyName={propertyName}

public object SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                  //Do the property assignment
            }
        }
```

When I visit help page, it shows following [image]

When I try to invoke the method from fiddler, using XML example, it works fine, object propertyValue equals to POST value.

XML POST example:

```
POST http://localhost:99/webapi/Settings/SetPropertyValue?propertyName=myProperty HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:99
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<anyType>
  true
</anyType>
```

But how to POST JSON in this case? Does JSON handles "simple" data types, like object or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see there is no body you send. So both the XML and JSON bodies are empty.

You place all your properties in the query string.

I was reading [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations) about it and it seems you have to start your method with `Post` to make it a HTTP POST instead of GET.

> **Quote:**
>
> Note two things about this method:
>
> The method name starts with "Post...". To create a new product, the
>   client sends an HTTP POST request.

This is my test code. Maybe it is useful to you:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:12345/api/Values");

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("5");

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/json";

request.Method = "POST";

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The controller action involved here:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    // check the value here
}
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer, as I completely don't understand, what did you mean..

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems that you don't understand, what exactly I'm asking. I'm ABLE to post object as XML, but how to post object as JSON? My code above is already working and accepting posts, but it seems, that I cant post simple data type as JSON.
To mark method as post, I've used [HttpPost] above it.

Comment: Did you send the content type in the request? `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Of course I do! Just tell me, pleae, how to POST simple data type as a JSON? Not a DataContract class, serialized as JSON object, but just String for exaple.

Comment: As I see, Web-Api, when serializing JSON does this: If there's a class, like 
`class Person
{
   string Name;
}` and we're getting or posting an object of the class, JSON object will look like `{Name:"John Doe"}`, but if we return simple type, like string "John Doe", we'll get `John Doe` as a response, which is not recognized, as valid JSON, but I'm able to fetch and post the value from my C#, Fiddler and Java clients, so problem is, basically, solved. Thanks for your effort!